# count subsets with given constraints

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms

We are given N elements . We need to count number of such subsets that satisfy following conditions :

1. If ith element is present then (i-1) and (i+1) can't be present.
2. Additon of any of the other element that is not currently included in subset results in violation of first rule. That means if we introduce ith element then (i+1) or (i-1) is present in that subset earlier.

For N=5,there are 4 valid subsets = ({1,4},{2,4},{1,3,5},{2,5})

Like {2,5} is valid subset because : 
1) 2 and 5 are not adjacent.
2) If we add 1, then 1 and 2 become adjacent.  If we add 3, then 2 and 3 become ajacent .If we add 4, then 4 and 5 will become adjacent. Hence we cant add any of remaining students.So it satisfies both rules (1) and (2).

Similarly {1,4} , {2,4} , {1,3,5} are valid.

{1,5} is not valid because :

If we add 3 in this subset ,still no adjacent element.Hence,it doesn't satisfy property (2).

{1,2,5} is not valid because :
1 and 2 are adjacent. Hence,it doesn't satisfy property (a).

Similarly the remaining 25 subsets are invalid.
Thus ,for N=5 , valid subsets(output) = 4

How to find it for given N ?

Comment: You might state it with "inclusion" instead of "addition" because for a second there I was thinking addition as in $a+b$.

Comment: Do you know how to solve linear recurrences?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah I do know . What's recurrence here?

Comment: Another way to express the rule for valid subsets is that the difference between successive elements must be $2$ or $3$ and at each end you must have the end or next to end element.  This might suggest a recurrence approach.

Comment: I see only a complicated solution.  You could define $\phi(n)$ resp. $\chi(n)$ as the number of sets $A\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\}$ which fulfill your premise plus $n\in A$ resp. $n\notin A$.  Then you have $\phi(n+2)=\chi(n)+\chi(n+1)$, $\chi(n+1)=\phi(n)$ if I'm not mistaken...  If you find this helpful I can formulate it as an answer with more details.

Comment: @fweth why two different functions ?

Comment: @RossMillikan Me too thinking in same direction. But no success yet

Comment: Couldn't think of something else.  But that says nothing, if you come up with a simpler recursion please share, I'm kind of interested now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A(n)$ be the number of acceptable subsets out of $n$ that include $n$ Then $A(n)=A(n-2)+A(n-3)$.  The number of subsets out of $n$ total is $A(n)+A(n-1)$

Comment: A(n)=A(n−2)+A(n−3) is solution then right ?

Comment: Can you tell me what will be value for N=30 as I have solution for N=30. Also let me know what will be its base cases

Comment: @user3804397: If I made no arithmetic errors, it’s $4410$.

Comment: The base cases are $A(1)=1$ because you can have $\{1\}$, $A(2)=1$, $A(3)=1$ because you can have $\{1,3\}$